# Missing String in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have this project where i one of the requirements is that in the string values it needs to say "none" or "null", 
I know how to do it if it was a interger or numeric value but in this case with the string value I do not know how to put "none " in an empty cell.

please help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RECODE  (' '='none').
EXECUTE.

or

RECODE  (' '='null').
EXECUTE.

If you use the menus, Transform>Recode into Same Variables, specify the variable(s) to apply it to, click the Old and New Values button, put a space in the old values slot, the desired text in the new values slot, click Add, then Continue, and OK (or paste if desired).